# How to add astric mark to listbox based on id

Tags: javascript, jquery, listbox

In my Asp web application I'm using JSON data to populate listbox.

part of my JSON as follows,

```
[  
   {  
      "UserId":10259,
      "FullName":"jhno doil",
      "BID":""
   },
   {  
      "UserId":10405,
      "FullName":"Adam mark",
      "BID":"10261"
   },
   {  
      "UserId":16224,
      "FullName":"silvester",
      "BID":""
   },
   {  
      "UserId":10416,
      "FullName":"Arnetta Chatcho",
      "BID":"1"
   },
   {  
      "UserId":10244,
      "FullName":"Ashanti Bueti",
      "BID":"1000"
   }
]
```

using above JSON I'm populate listbox like this,

```
function GetSupervisorComplete(result, status) {
    "use strict";
    var data = jQuery.parseJSON(result.d);
    var lstsupervisor = $("[id*=lbSupervisor]");
    lstsupervisor.empty();
    $.each(data, function () {

        lstsupervisor.append($("<option></option>").val(this['UserId']).html(this['FullName']));
    });
}
```

How to add `astric mark(*)` to option if `BID = ""` ? as below image.when I click the option from the list astric mark`*`, cannot be shown in the placeholder. how can I add **`*`** to list?

[image]

Comment: @sureshbambhaniya please don't edit to add unnecessary tags. ASP.Net is not relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

With a basic ternary operation. Modifying the last line like the following should do the trick.

```
lstsupervisor.append($("<option></option>").val(this['UserId']).html(this['FullName'] + (this['BID'] === '' ? '*' : '')));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ternary to add the `*` to the `html()` based on the value of `BID`.

You can also use `map()` to build a single array of HTML strings. You can use this to improve performance by only calling `append()` once. Try this:

```
function GetSupervisorComplete(result, status) {
  var data = jQuery.parseJSON(result.d);
  var $lstsupervisor = $("[id*=lbSupervisor]").empty();

  var html = data.map(function(o) {
    var name = o.FullName + (!o.BID ? ' *' : '');
    return `<option value="${o.UserId}">${name}</option>`;
  });
  $lstsupervisor.append(html);
}
```

Comment: this works, but when I click the item astric also showing in the placeholder.how to avoid it, pls see the image https://i.imgur.com/DAQs3TX.png

Comment: There's nothing you can do about that, it's how the control works. It shows the full text which was selected, which now include the `*` for certain options

Comment: Haven't any possible way to avoid this? and how can I set astric color red?

Comment: It depends on the listbox control you're using. Can you link to it's documentation? With regard to making the asterisk red, again it depends on the control you're using

Comment: I's using Jquery multisector

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
lstsupervisor.append($("<option></option>").val(this['UserId']).html(this['FullName'] + this['BID']?"":"*" ));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take extra variable which first find that astric mark should be added or not. You may do like as follow:

```
function GetSupervisorComplete(result, status) {
    "use strict";
        var data = jQuery.parseJSON(result.d);
        var lstsupervisor = $("[id*=lbSupervisor]");
        lstsupervisor.empty();
        $.each(data, function () {
             var astric_style = this['BID'] == '' ? '*' : '';
             lstsupervisor.append($("<option></option>").val(this['UserId']).html(this['FullName']+astric_style));
    });
```

Comment: when I click the item astric also showing in the placeholder.how to avoid it, pls see the image https://i.imgur.com/DAQs3TX.png